# C# - Inserting into a table in a method and selecting it outside of that method

Tags: transactions, insert-into

I have a transaction, there is a method calling in the tran. which makes insertion into a table, after that when i select the row that i have inserted, i find no result

how can i solve this problem without changing this structure or what else can i do?

Thanks in advance

```
using (TransactionScope scope01 = new TransactionScope(option01, span01))
 {

   InsertIntoTable(); // inserting a row into Foo table , insert into...executenonquery

   string smcd = "select * from Foo Where XCol=@XParm";

   ExecuteQuery(scmd); // This Returns no result



   scope01.Complete();
 }
```

Comment: in the InsertIntoTable(), i can select the data after insertion,
 why cannot i select it outside of the method?

Answer (score 0):

solved, i realized that i used a different connection on select statement